# 2048 Game code snippet to manipulate spawning

Tags: javascript, arrays, code-snippets

## Hey guys!

I've found online this code-snippet:

```
(function(M, _, $) {
_ = M.random.bind(M), $ = [];
M.random = function() {
    $.length || ['0','4'].
    forEach(function(x, i) {
        $.push(i ? x - 2 : x / (function(d, o, i) {
            for (i = d.length; i— > 0; o[d[i].className.match(/\-.\-./)[0]] = 1);
            return 16 - Object.keys(o).length
        }(document.querySelectorAll('.tile'), {})))
    });
    return $.pop()
}
}(Math))
```

If you open the [2048 game](https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) and paste this in the console the effect is that all new tiles are spawning at the 1st position on the grid with the value 4. I hardly want to understand how this code works but i dont get it without your help. I would appreciate your help to resolve this codeblock.

Avanatiker

Comment: It overwrites the `Math.random` function so that instead of random values, 2048 gets some not-so-random values.

Comment: That code snippet makes me cringe

Comment: First thank you for your answers. This helped me alot. No i have the question what causes this error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`
This error appears if every grid position is filled und i cant merge the tiles together. And is there any possibility to fix this bug?

Comment: Okay guys ive found the root of all evil. Thank you again :)